# How to do nsqd load balancing with its sticky connections?

Tags: go, kubernetes, load-balancing, nsq

I have a golang microservice project in kubernetes environment, that is running several `nsqd-0`, `nsqd-1`, `...` pods, which are controlled by its statefulSet and grouped under `nsqd` service.

The problem is when I want to make a producer, i import `github.com/nsqio/go-nsq` and create it `p := nsq.NewProducer('nsqd:4150', nsq.NewConfig())`

But the connections are sticky (persistent) so what happens is service provides me ip adress of random pod (say it `nsqd-2`), and all traffic goes to it. others are unused at all

For now I am using awful workaround, every 5 seconds I `p.Stop()` current producer and reinitialize so it connects to a different pod. But how to load balance it normally? Is there any cloud-native simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is we can inititalize n times based on number of nsqd and put round robin logic behind it on client side

Comment: Hi, thanks, but what is the way to know N? Also what if n is changing during runtime?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).